# AlertDialo gets dull in Night mode Flutter

Tags: themes, flutter-alertdialog

I have two themes in my flutter app, the issue is when Night theme is selected, the alert dialogs also appear to be dark & dull. How can I increase the alert dialog's brightness level while using the dark theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the backgroundColor of the AlertDialog to a bright color...

Comment: Thank you! Adding property backgroundColor: Colors.white, in AlertDialog solved the problem.